# Will ActiveRecordStore solve my login lost due to crumbled cookie woes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

Here's the scenario: our site uses Rails' default CookieStore for saving session information. Doing so suits our needs fine except for the fact that some customers who "login" on our site lose their authentication because they either:

1. Are (unnecessarily) private browsing at a level that rejects cookies
2. Are browsing with some other setting that rejects/stomps cookies

In that case our site can't find an id it needs to operate, assumes the user is up to no good, and effectively logs them out.

My question is two-fold:

1. Would using ActiveRecordStore solve my problem since the id I need would be stored in the DB? How does ActiveRecordStore persist session ids between requests?
2. Other than sessions is there any reliable way to carry an indication of authentication between requests?

Regarding #1, if ActiveRecordStore needs a cookie to store the session id then moving to it doesn't make much sense because the problem would still exist.

Regarding #2, the only thing I can think of is passing the necessary id in request parameters and using timestamps to require that a user's requests happen within a certain timeframe (which makes sense in this part of our system). Drawback: there would always be a window open to malicious activity, albeit a much smaller one than if there was no such constraint.

Currently we're tackling the problem non-programmatically: just alert the user of what is happening by directing them to a help page that explains how to solve the issue. If they can't, contact us for assistance. This may be the right solution, and if this issue is only ever going to affect 10% of our users (which it is so far--this is the first time its happened), then it may be not be worth changing the code.

Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Per http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6372-action-controller-session

> Your application has a session for each user in which you can store small amounts of data that will be persisted between requests. The session is only available in the controller and can use one of a number of different storage mechanisms:
>
> - CookieStore - Stores everything on the client.
> - DRBStore - Stores the data on a DRb client.
> - MemCacheStore - Stores the data in MemCache.
> - ActiveRecordStore - Stores the data in a database using Active Record.
>
> All session stores store the session id in a cookie - there is no other way of passing it to the server. Most stores also use this key to locate the session data on the server.

I guess you could inject the encrypted session id into the page HTML and then use javascript to pass that information with every internal link or form that the user submits, thus recreating the cookie functionality. But if your users intentionally turned off cookies, they probably wouldn't like you doing this...

Comment: Just as I expected, and explained very clearly--that's what I couldn't find with Google (explicit confirmation that session id is in cookie with ActiveRecordStore). Thanks!